# JavaScript based advanced table search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a way to filter a table using Javascript. While the snippet below filters, it does so by using all the table's cell contents, but I am looking for a way to either specify a criteria (index=1) or only by making the function only search through "Index".

The search function is triggered by keyup. the function below queryString gets an ID from an other side and is supposed to pre-filter the table. Is there a way to pre-/retrigger the search function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $("#search").val();
    var listItem = $('.results tbody').children('tr');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array){
          return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });
      
    $(".results tbody tr").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
      $(this).attr('visible','false');
    });

    $(".results tbody tr:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e){
      $(this).attr('visible','true');
    });

    // Search Count item hits
    var jobCount = $('.results tbody tr[visible="true"]').length;
    $('.counter').text(jobCount + ' item');
    if(jobCount == '0') {$('.no-result').show();}
      else {$('.no-result').hide();}
  });

  // Parameter Passing
  var queryString = new Array();
  $(function() {
    if (queryString.length == 0) {
        if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
            var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                queryString[key] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    if (queryString["id"] != null) {
         $('#search').val(queryString["id"])
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.results tr[visible='false'],
.no-result{
  display:none;
}

.results tr[visible='true']{
  display:table-row;
}

.counter{
  padding:8px; 
  color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group pull-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="search">
      </div>
      <span class="counter pull-right"></span>
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover results">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
          </tr>
            <tr class="warning no-result">
              <td colspan="4"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> No result</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>112</td>
            <td>Content112</td>
            <td>Content2</td>
            <td>Content329</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent112</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent123</td>
            <td>SomeOtherContent3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>329</td>
            <td>CompletelyDifferentContent123</td>
            <td>CompletelyDifferentContent2</td>
            <td>CompletelyDifferentContent329</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: `$("#search").trigger("keyup");`

Comment: Why are you extending jQuery on every keyup? Move that outside...

Comment: Thanks, that worked! One of the two problems is solved already then.

Comment: So select only the first cell in your filter and read that text, the the entire row's text

Comment: Can you give an example? "Advanced" filtering would be the best honestly, by somehow linking the `<th>Index</th>` with the `index=` in search bar.

Comment: `td:nth-child(1)`

Comment: I mean could you give the code snippet, since I obviously have no idea where to add this to.